# Правильный занос данных в бд

Tags: php, html

Если в html коде value='1', то как это сказать пхп, что это значит, героя зовут Влад =)

**Добавлено.**

Например заносим данные в бд

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `startpoke` (name) values('$name')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Но этих покемонов много, но в html коде сказано, что value='1' как сказать пхп, что покемона зовут Бульбазавр?

Comment: И при этом мы в регистрации, этого покемона выбираем !

Comment: Что того зовут так то, а того так то, но мы выбираем Бульбазавра, 
<input name='startpoke' type='radio' value='1' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>001 Bulbasaur</b><img src=img/001.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1></p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Материал для размышлений
 1. почему в php уходит цифра, а не 001 Bulbasaur если имя важнее?
 2. судя по всему вы понимаете что героя можно переименовать, потому используете id - тогда странно что у вас в таблице с характеристиками героя нет поля с его именем...

`hero['id'] = 1; hero['name'] = '001 Bulbasaur'; hero['class'] = 'gopneg';`

и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Ну смотри, 1 - это ведь id пользователя?
Т.е. получется что-то типа такого:

```
$id = $_POST['iduser'];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$name = $row['username']; // Это и будет имя пользователя
```

Конечно же значения поменяй на свои

Comment: Блин, вы меня не поняли =( Есть пользователь, он при регистрации выбирает себе героя, которым будет играть, Но чтоб определить как зовут этого героя я ввожу value!

Comment: Ну, пользователь выбирает "001 Bulbasaur", в php уходит цифра 1 вместо этого, нужно сделать, чтобы php понял, что цифра 1 означает "001 Bulbasaur"?